# Join city_name for users and for an event

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to get the city name for an event and the city name for where a user lives. They both have a postalcode, that corresponds to a city_name in the table `cities`.

My query so far:

```
SELECT
    meetups.meetup_name,
    meetups.meetup_text,
    users.username,
    cities.city_name
FROM
    meetups, users, cities
WHERE
    meetups.url_meetup = ? and users.id = meetups.author_id and cities.postalcode = meetups.postalcode
```

What i still need to get is the city name for the user.

My tables looks as follows:

```
meetups =>
    id
    meetup_url
    meetup_name
    meetup_text
    author_id
    postalcode

users =>
    id
    username
    postalcode

cities =>
    postalcode
    city_name
```

Comment: There is no column `meetup_city` in ur table definition. In ur where clause you cant use the alias, u need to use the actual column name instead.

Comment: I just thought that maybe it would work as an alias for cities.city_name. But i'm aware that this is probably not right at all, but i just need some help to figure out how to do it then.

Comment: Use `cities.city_name` in the where clause. The same goes for the `author_city` alias. Also u have two aliases for the same column, not sure why.

Comment: Ok can see i missed some things in the last query, have been messing around with it for a bit. I edited it. From here, now i need the city name for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    meetups.meetup_name,
    meetups.url_meetup,
    meetups.meetup_text,
    users.username,
    c1.city_name as meetup_city,
    c2.city_name as user_city   
FROM
meetups, users, cities c1, cities c2   
WHERE
url_meetup = ? 
and users.id = meetups.author_id 
and c1.postalcode = meetups.postalcode
and c2.postalcode = users.postalcode
```

This should get u the name of the user city as well.

Comment: That was exactly what i needed. Thankyou! (: What can i search for to learn about this?

Comment: No problem. Well, I guess Google is always your friend, but if you want to check out books this might give a few pointer: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975229/a-good-book-for-sql-queries`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
meetups.meetup_name,
meetups.meetup_text,
users.username,
meetups.postalcode as mPC,
(select cities.city_name from cities where cities.postalcode = mPC) as mCity,
users.postalcode as uPC,
(select cities.city_name from cities where cities.postalcode = uPC) as uCity,
FROM
meetups, users, cities
WHERE
meetups.url_meetup = ?
AND users.id = meetups.author_id;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want to get a city name for the event itself and a different city name for the author of the event (user).

Comment: There, how about something like that?